# select most specific join result

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to make mysql return the most specific discount for an shopitem, as several discounts might apply. My tables and data are as follows (columns not relevant have been left out):

```
Item
  itemId   brand    supplier   price
  ======   =====    ========   =====
  Item1    Brand1   Supply1    100
  Item2    Brand2   Supply1    100
  Item3    Brand3   Supply1    100
  Item4    Brand4   Supply2    100

Discount
  discountId   itemId   brand    supplier   discountPrice
  ==========   ======   ======   ========   =============
  Discount1    (null)   (null)   Supply1    80
  Discount2    (null)   Brand2   Supply1    60
  Discount3    Item3    (null)   (null)     40
```

And my expected output of the query would be

```
itemId  price  discountPrice
===================================
Item1   100    80
Item2   100    60
Item3   100    40
Item4   100    (null)
```

As you can see my rules are

1. Supplier discount is least specifc
2. Supplier + brand discount is more specifc
3. ItemId discount is most specifc

A normal left join with or on the clauses however will return all combinations and not the most specific discount. How can I achieve this?

`select item.itemId, item.price, discount.discountPrice from item left join discount on (item.itemId = discount.itemId) or (item.brand = discount.brand and item.supplier = discount.supplier) or (item.supplier = discount.supplier AND discount.brand IS NULL)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEEXample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c5a6/1)**

```
SELECT i.itemId, 
       i.price, 
       COALESCE(d.discountPrice, d2.discountPrice, d3.discountPrice) AS discountPrice 
FROM item i
LEFT JOIN discount d 
  ON i.itemId = d.itemId
LEFT JOIN discount d2
  ON i.brand = d2.brand
  AND i.supplier = d2.supplier 
LEFT JOIN discount d3
 ON i.supplier = d3.supplier 
 AND d3.brand IS NULL
```

Result:

```
| ITEMID | PRICE | DISCOUNTPRICE |
----------------------------------
|  Item1 |   100 |            80 |
|  Item2 |   100 |            60 |
|  Item3 |   100 |            40 |
|  Item4 |   100 |        (null) |
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I would do it:
Use a separate left join for all the three discounts and select the most specific from them

```
Select 
    i.itemId, 
    i.price,
    coalesce(spec3.discountPrice, spec2.discountPrice, spec1.discountPrice)
from item i
left join Discount spec3 on (i.itemId = spec3.itemId)
left join Discount spec2 on (i.supplier = spec2.supplier and i.brand = spec2.brand)
left join Discount spec1 on (i.supplier = spec1.supplier)
```

The query above might contain some syntax errors, I don't have a mysql server nearby to actually run it.